# HTML form required fields issue from mobile devices

Tags: php, html, css, validation

I'm looking for some help from one of you as an expert. I have a HTML form published on my website, and this html form contains required fields which are not required when its submitted via mobile devices. Therefore I keep receiving blank forms from mobile users. Please suggest me solution, or point out the issue I possible missed out.

Thank you very much!!!

The html form:

```
    <form id="form2" action="../../tbs_services/tbs_facial/facial_athlone.php" method="post" name="form2">
<table width="auto">
  <tr>
    <td height="10" colspan="2"><p class="h_text">First Name:</p></td>
    <td width="240"><input type="text" required class="textfield" id="firstname" name="firstname" size="40"></td>
    <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top"></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="10" colspan="2"><p class="h_text">Last Name:</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" required class="textfield2" id="lastname" name="lastname" size="40"></td>
    <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top"></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="10" colspan="2"><p class="h_text">Email Address:</p></td>
    <td><input type="email" required class="email" id="email" name="email" size="40"></td>
    <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top"></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="10" colspan="2"><p class="h_text">Mobile No:</p></td>
    <td><input type="tel" required class="tel" id="tel" name="tel" size="40"></td>
    <td width="104">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="70">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="10" colspan="2"><p class="h_text">Preferred Time:</p></td>
    <td><select name="select" style="width: 184px" id="preferredtime">
      <option>Morning</option>
      <option>Afternoon</option>
      <option>Evening</option>
    </select></td>
    <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top"></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="10" colspan="2"><p class="h_text">Preferred Date:</p></td>
    <td><input type="date" required value="dd-mm-yy" class="date" name="date" id="date" style="width: 183px"></td>
    <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top"></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="10" colspan="2"><p class="h_text">What would you like to book?</p></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top"></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td width="23" height="30"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="YES" id="emfacial"></td>
    <td width="233"><p class="h_text">Express Mini Facial</br>
      15-30min - €15</p></td>
    <td width="253">&nbsp;</p></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="50">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input id="submit_form2" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Here is the PHP file for mailing the submitted form:

```
/* Email Description */
$emailSubject = 'Athlone Mini Facial Appointment Enquiry'; /*Email Subject!*/
$webMaster = '<-- my email address -->';

/* Data Variables */
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$select = $_POST['select'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$checkbox1 = $_POST['checkbox1'];


$body = <<<EOD
Booking from (www.thebodyshop.ie)<br><br>
Hi Athlone store, you have received an appointment enquiry.<br>
Please contact customer below to confirm availability.
<br><br><br>
First name: $firstname <br>
Last name: $lastname <br>
Email address: $email <br>
Mobile no: $tel <br>
Preferred time: $select <br>
Preferred date: $date <br>
Express Mini Facial: $checkbox1 <br>

EOD;
$headers = "From: $firstname\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body,
$headers);


/* Results landing as HTML */
$theResults = <<<EOD
<html>
<head>
<title>sent message</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL=http://www.thebodyshop.ie/services.html">
<style type="text/css">

<!--

body {

background-color: rgba(46,186,237,.7);/*Stylesheet to the landing page!*/

font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

font:normal 300%/1em "TBSactivist", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

text-transform:uppercase;

color:white;

text-align: center;

text-decoration: none;

padding-top: 200px;

margin-left: auto;

margin-right: auto;

max-width: 100% !important;

height:auto;

}

-->

</style>
</head>
<div align="center">Thank you for your booking enquiry.<br><br>A staff member will be in touch within 72 hrs.</div>
</body>
</html>
EOD;
echo "$theResults";
?>
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Why does it matter? If the mobile users need to send in some of the fields but not all of them, then as long as you log them as mobile users, blank responses are completely valid. If a mobile user never needs to fill out the form at all, don't give them the option - hide it in your mobile site.

Comment: I need as required to fill out the mobile no, email address to be able to confirm the booking enquiry.

Comment: Then you're inevitably going to get blank field, unless you use an entirely separate table to hold mobile user information, which would seem counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you need to include some sort of server-side validation for your fields. This will also help ensure people on out-dated browsers fill in the required fields.

Something in your php like:

```
session_start();

$errors = array();

if(!$firstname)
    $errors['firstname'] = 'Please enter your first name';

if(!$lastname)
    $errors['lastname'] = 'Please enter your first name';
```

etc..

Before you build your email, you can then check for errors:

```
if(count($errors)) {
    $_SESSION['data'] = $_POST;
    $_SESSION['errors'] = $errors;
    header('Location: BACK TO YOUR FORM');
}
```

from here, you have the data they entered in the `$_SESSION['data']` variable, so you can fill in the ones they have and then display the errors of the missing fields.

Comment: So I simply include your lines to my php file, and it should work?

Comment: It will take some poking and twisting about - my code is more a concept than actual working